# How to send specific rows of excel to data provider in testNG?

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have created an excel containing multiple rows, each row corresponding to a test case. The Excel has around 22 columns (parameters) including a "Flag" column.

I want the Dataprovider to return only those columns which has a value 'Y' in the excel column. The use case is that when the client wants to run a particular test case, they only need to flag it to Y or N. How can I achieve this is in TestNG with Selenium?

My colleague had helped me to achieve this using following code, but this does not work as per my new code structure.

```
@DataProvider(name = "Order") 
     public Object[][] menu() 
     { 
         Object[][] data = UtilLibrary.getData("Order");
         int intColCount = UtilLibrary.datatable.getColumnCount("Order");

         int j = 0; 
         int arrRowCount=0; 
         for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
             if((data[i][intColCount-1]).equals("Y"))
             { 
                 arrRowCount++; 

                 } 
             } 
                j=0;

                Object[][] retData = new Object[arrRowCount][intColCount]; 
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                { 
                    if ((data[i][intColCount-1]).equals("Y")) {
                        retData[j] = data[i]; j++; }
                } 
                return retData; 
     }
```

The above code sends only the record/s having flag='Y' in the excel to the Dataprovider. But, it was working only when the test script had a single @Test method having all automation steps, while now I have multiple @Test methods to simulate the same steps to which I have passed this same Dataprovider (Order).

Let me know if someone has achieved this using a similar code or if TestNG has a specific feature to send filtered rows of excel to the Dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed the issue. The reason why the above given code for rows having flag = 'Y' in Excel was not working with multiple @Test methods was only due to a silly mistake. The mistake was that I had changed the excel structure a bit and did not modify the above code as per the index of the new flag column.